# How to build a shopping cart with mvc in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart

I'm a new to MVC in asp.net. I want to build a shopping cart with MVC (without using EF Code First as [Music store mvc shopping cart](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-8)). Anyone can show me a simple code or tutorial that I can learn?

Answer (score 9):

Well, i will suggest you to go to codeplex.com and search for the shopping carts. You will find alot of working examples. [Here](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=shopping%20cart&ac=8) is the link.

You can download any project. If you have basic understanding of .Net then you do not need a step by step tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

i give best option for that Microsoft provide one complete example for that "MVC Music Store" it some kind of hand on lab it's also have sopping inside that example and lots of other thing that u helpful

online example and tutorial [click here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store)

offline tutorial (PDF) [click here](http://docrepository.googlecode.com/files/MVC%20Music%20Store%20-%20Tutorial%20-%20v1.0.pdf)

complete example (code and PDF) [click here](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379)